# "http://localhost/Identity/account" is accessible, but don't have it in my project. Why is the there, and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I did run the identity scaffolding a while back, but I deleted it again along with all files shortly after. I do intent to bring it back later though, but I don't want it at that URL.

I've tried deleting bin/obj and even moved it to a different computer. There's no register.cshtml file anywhere in my project, yet, I can still access the Url, login, change password etc..

What is it causing the URL to be accessible, and how do I disable it?

[image]
Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        builder.UseStartup<Program>();

        var build = builder.Build();
        build.Run();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddScoped(typeof(AdminBuilder));

        var mvc = services.AddMvc();
        mvc.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

IdentityHostingStartup.cs

```
[assembly: HostingStartup(typeof(MyProjectWebsite.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace MyProjectWebsite
{
    public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => 
            {
                services.AddDbContext<MyProjectDbContext>();
                services.AddDefaultIdentity<SMyProjectUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyProjectDbContext>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `app.UseAuthentication` for?

Comment: @spender Honestly not sure what that is for - yet. But removing it didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure that's all of your config? Identity has a "default UI", which is included via `AddDefaultUI()`, when configuring Identity. Additionally, the `AddDefaultIdentity` extension calls `AddDefaultUI`. However, neither of those are in the code you posted, and there's in fact no reference to Identity at all in what you've provided. Assuming you have none of the scaffolded Razor Pages files for Identity in your project, then the default UI is really the only way you could still be getting these views.

Comment: @spender Ah should have included that as well. I've added my "IdentityHostingStartup.cs" to the questions. Beyond that, I don't think I have any more relevant.

Comment: Well there you go: you ran AddDefaultIdentity. Did you look up what that actually does?

Comment: Thanks, got rid of the class and manually added all services needed, got it working now. Thanks a ton.